# Bug in Scalajs when compiling pattern matching?

Tags: compilation, scala.js

*I currently cannot reproduce this in a minimum working example, but I'm working on it.*

Adding a line in a dead code causes a crash at run-time.
Here are the relevant code snippets, first from the scala file:

```
// We are inside an object. Expr is a trait with many case classes.
case class Problem(in: Expr, out: Expr)
type RepairOutput = Either[String, Stream[Expr]]

private sealed trait RepairFinalTransform
...
private sealed trait TransformExtend extends RepairFinalTransform {
  def continuation(repair: Problem => RepairOutput)
    : Expr => RepairOutput
}
private case class TransformSolutionAndContinue(f: Expr => (Problem, Expr => Expr)) extends TransformExtend {
  def continuation(repair: Problem => RepairOutput): Expr => RepairOutput = (x: Expr) => f(x) match {
    case (p, rewriter) => repair(p) andMap rewriter
  }
}
private case class TransformAndContinue(f: Expr => RepairOutput) extends TransformExtend {
  def continuation(repair: Problem => RepairOutput): Expr => RepairOutput = f
}
```

The following code snippet

```
case c: TransformExtend =>
        r = r andThen c.continuation(_repair)
```

, when working, is compiled as:

```
if ($is_Lexample_LambdaCalculus$TransformExtend(x1)) {
    var x5 = $as_Lexample_LambdaCalculus$TransformExtend(x1);
    var e$1 = r;
    r = new $c_Lexample_LambdaCalculus$Retransformer().init___s_util_Either(e$1).andThen__F1__s_util_Either(x5.continuation__F1__F1(new $c_sjsr_AnonFunction1().init___sjs_js_Function1((function($this) {
      return (function(original_problem$2) {
        var original_problem = $as_Lexample_LambdaCalculus$Problem(original_problem$2);
        return $m_Lexample_LambdaCalculus$().$$undrepair__Lexample_LambdaCalculus$Problem__s_util_Either(original_problem)
      })
    })(this))))
  }
```

However, as soon as I add one occurrence of `TransformAndContinue(???)` (I did not have any before) in a place that is currently never executed, the above code becomes:

```
if ($is_Lexample_LambdaCalculus$TransformExtend(x1)) {
    var x5 = $as_Lexample_LambdaCalculus$TransformExtend(x1);
    var e$1 = r;
    r = new $c_Lexample_LambdaCalculus$Retransformer().init___s_util_Either(e$1).andThen__F1__s_util_Either(x5.f$1)
}
```

Note that `x5` is supposed to be a type cast to `TransformExtend`, which does not have the field `f`, only the `continue` method. Since `f` exists in both classes, its return type differs. Besides, the case class `TransformSolutionAndContinue` was used in many other places, so there is no reason why it calls `f` instead of `continue`.
So the translation to Javascript seems wrong (and actually, the errors fail on this point). I'm using `scalajs 0.6.19` and compile using `fastOptJS` and `scalatest`.

Can you tell me what to change in my code so that the compilation is correct? Is it a known bug?

Comment: Are there any instances of `TransformSolutionAndContinue`? If not this is the optimizer minimizing dispatch and inlining accessors.

Comment: Yes there are instances of `TransformSolutionAndContinue`. And this is what causes the bug. When in the above, `x1` is an instance of `TransformSolutionAndContinue`, the code uses the parameter `f` as if it was an `Expr => RepairOutput`, but it is effectively an `Expr => (Problem, Expr => Expr)`. Therefore, after `f` executes on an argument, I would get the exception `UndefinedBehavior: (<problem>, <function>) is not an instance of Either`

Comment: I tried to clean and rebuild, and I cannot reproduce this bug anymore.

Comment: Yeah, so you probably got hit by an issue in the incremental part of the optimizer. Try reproducing by reverting to working state, clean, fastoptJS, change, fastoptJS.

Comment: I did not commit my code for a long time so I unfortunately cannot do this.